# A comparison between the verb "endure" and "last"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, verbs, word-difference

Please let me know which one of the following choices work properly in the self-made sentence below:

> My old car has.......well over these years
>
> - **a)** endured
> - **b)** lasted

For me, only the choice 'b' works here properly or at least fits better.

Comment: Informally you could also say "My old car has *held up* well over the years." See [*hold up*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/held+up): "4. To continue to function without losing force or effectiveness; cope: *managed to hold up under the stress*." Also I wouldn't use "these" unless a specific time period was mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

*To last* simply means to exist over a period of time.

*To endure* means to exist despite challenges or adversity.

*Endure* is a more colorful term because it means it has "survived" against external things, but *last* isn't wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that the verb *to serve* is going to be better word choice here, given the context of the sentence:

> My old car has **served** me well over all these years.